# Hybrid web app - Android / iOS/ Amazon Fire TV

Tags: javascript, android, ios, cordova, amazon-fire-tv

I need to create a hybrid web app for Android, iOS and Amazon fire tv. Does anyone know a platform I can use to support all 3 of these in one place?

I've looked at Cordova and there used to be specific docs for all these platforms, now it only contains Android and iOS. Does anyone know if Android would cover Amazon Fire TV as well?

If Cordova isn't the option then any other suggestions are welcome!

Answer (score 0):

Cordova is a great way to create an app for Fire TV and, just by adding the Android platform to your setup, you should cover both Android and Fire TV

```
cordova platform add android
```

When the application runs on Fire TV, it will use the Amazon Webview which is an optimised version of the Android webview so you might see subtle differences performance wise.
One thing worth noting is that building cross platforms apps that provide a great user experience on TV can be tricky. You should not use the same UI as your iOS or mobile Android app as this will result in poor interactions on a 10-foot UI, you should map the remote keys appropriately and ensure the viewport and your CSS respond well to either 720p or 1080p.
More info on UI/UX on TV devices can be found on the [Developer Portal](https://developer.amazon.com/public/solutions/devices/fire-tv/docs/design-and-user-experience-guidelines).

In addition to that, have a look at the docs available on [Building web apps on Fire TV](https://developer.amazon.com/public/solutions/platforms/webapps/docs/getting-started-with-web-apps-for-fire-tv), the Appstore allows you to submit your web app in 3 ways:

1. Hosted - you submit the URL to your webapp and the Appstore will automatically package it with a Cordova-like wrapper
2. ZIP - you upload the zip file containing the HTML/CSS/JS and media files and the Appstore will automatically package it with a Cordova-like wrapper
3. Traditional - you create a new "Android app" in your console and upload your packaged Cordova APK

You should also consider using some frameworks that are already optimised for TV experiences, like the [Web App Starter Kit](https://developer.amazon.com/public/solutions/platforms/webapps/docs/the-web-app-starter-kit-for-fire-tv).

Answer (score 0):

I've heard of wrappers that can take an Amazon Fire TV web app (called a WASK) and make it into an Android based Fire TV channel.

Also, I wonder if Luca https://stackoverflow.com/users/3405496/luca-s has a solution for those of us who would like to redevelop a currently published WASK app to be compatible with an Ad Server ---  or if that won't work, is there a way to make a currently published WASK app redirect to a different App/Fire-TV-channel?